# When to use getStaticPaths()?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dynamic, static, next.js

Currently,An API call is done in one of the root components which stores the API data in a Singleton.

This singleton data must be accessed by the getStaticPaths(),but since the getStaticPaths() pre-renders it,the singleton is empty and returns a null object.

How do i send the paths data to getStaticPaths() such that it dynamically receives the data,or executes it after a period of time?

Answer (score 0):

It would be better if you could show some code here and explain a bit better what you are aiming for. From what I understand - You are making an API call (from getServerSideProps()?) and you might be getting some data you need to decide which page to render on build time via the getStaticPaths() method.

A possible solution would be to make the API call from the getStaticPaths() method only. I don't understand why you are making the API call from other function when you need that in getStaticPaths(). Here is a solution from the official docs -

```js
// This function gets called at build time
export async function getStaticPaths() {
  // Call an external API endpoint to get posts
  const res = await fetch('https://.../posts')
  const posts = await res.json()

  // Get the paths we want to pre-render based on posts
  const paths = posts.map((post) => ({
    params: { id: post.id },
  }))

  // We'll pre-render only these paths at build time.
  // { fallback: false } means other routes should 404.
  return { paths, fallback: false }
}
```

> This singleton data must be accessed by the getStaticPaths(),but since the getStaticPaths() pre-renders it,the singleton is empty and returns a null object.

Since getStaticPaths() is an async function you will not get an empty object as it will wait for the API request to complete. After you have the data you can use it in your getStaticPaths() function as per your need.

> How do i send the paths data to getStaticPaths() such that it dynamically receives the data,or executes it after a period of time?

getStaticPaths() runs only once at the build time, you cannot envoke it whenever you wish. If you want to delay it's execution than that can be done but I don't think it will serve your purpose.

The official docs are very comprehensive, do go through them to get better understanding of these data-fetching methods - https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching

Comment: Hey @Toughyear,I have a resource that is an asynchronous API call that is done during execution time rather than build time,which must be used by getStaticPaths.Any idea as to how i could achieve that?

Comment: and as to calling the api call outside the getStaticPaths, it is necessary to use the data from the api call within redux store. The api call can be done in getStaticPaths, but it reutruns undefined as the api is asynchronous.